# Suggestions on doing a difficult WinForms merge with subversion?

Tags: winforms, svn, merge, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

My manager wants me to move some specific features from our Subversion trunk to the branch we used for a beta release some months ago.

This is a multi-project, VS2008 solution using WinForms. The other projects are mainly support DLLs for the main project, which is mostly UI code.

We use both Ankh and Tortoise.

There have been multiple changes in all the projects, but I only want to merge **some** of the changes into the branch.

I've been using TortoiseMerge, merging my main form, compiling, and then merging associated projects based on compile errors, but it's going very slowly.

Problems I've been running into:

- merging changes to forms that touch both .cs and .designer.cs files
- changes that are dependent on changes to other projects, which cascade to yet more projects, etc.

Any suggestions on a better way to proceed?

Comment: Do you have access to a command-line SVN client? Because that would almost certainly be quicker than Tortoise. Then you could merge specific revisions really easily.

Comment: If you're having to merge the forms and then merge the support projects separately to get them to compile, it soulds like the checkins have not been very atomic in the past. Have people been making form changes, making assoicated changes to the support projects, and checking them in under different revision numbers?

Comment: @pjabbot - the checkins have been fairly atomic, the problem is caused by my approach.  I was just manually merging the latest working copy in the trunk with the working copy of the branch - which more and more, seems to be a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of futzing around with SVN merging, I've come to the conclusion that my best approach is to manually merge my desired features to the beta branch.

Seems to be the best way to fully control the process, and only get the changes I want.

The Winforms .designer.cs files are the biggest problem. The VS designer moves things around a lot when you add new controls, and this creates all kinds of conflicts when trying to merge, which are difficult to resolve.

**Edit**

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Opened both the trunk and branch projects in separate Visual Studio
   instances
2. For each form, copied and pasted new controls from trunk to branch,
   using the VS IDE designers.  This ensured that the .designer.cs
   files would be valid.
3. Used [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/) to merge the form's .cs file, on a line by line
   basis, so I only picked up the changes I wanted.  (In some cases -
   when I wanted all the changes - I just copied the entire file(s)
   from trunk to branch folders.)
4. Tried to build the project, which usually caused compile errors
5. Based on the errors, merged other files with WinMerge until I had a
   clean compile
6. Repeated the steps above until all my desired features were merged
7. Tested all the merged features

It went pretty smoothly, once I figured out the basic approach.

Comment: I would recommend trying the free (as in beer) SourceGear DiffMerge (http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) or another tool that allows using a 3 way merge.
WinMerge just allows two way merges, so your tool can't see what changed since the base version: just how the two versions differ.

DiffMerge adds a bit of knowledge about programming languages which makes resolving conflicts much easier than many simple line based diff tools.

Comment: Note that the latest DiffMerge is not automatically detected by the stable AnkhSVN releases as SourceGear decided to rename the program and all registry keys pointing to it in the last update. (Fixed in the daily builds of AnkhSVN 2.1,2.2 and 2.3)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.  I had been using TortoiseMerge with AnkhSVN, which I believe does a 3 way merge.  However, it would not save merged files to the branch for some reason, and I didn't have time to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to command line, you could try to generate patches from each branch (or trunk) with `svn diff` by specifying the min and max revisions containing the specific features you need to move.

These patches (probably) won't apply automatically on your target branch, but the amount of rework will be minimized. Of course, you should start with the oldest features and work your way back to head.

**EDIT**

I am having another idea/suggestion. You could synchronize the content of your beta target branch with what is on trunk and then disactivate the features your boss does not want on the beta branch. It could mean less work than moving features patch by patch.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion (using the Ankh merge wizard instead of the command line).  The problem was that this pulled in a lot of other changes, and we don't have time to retest them.  It was worth a try, though - thanks for the suggestion.